# How to draw a graph from specific lines of CSV file?

Tags: pgfplots, csv

I would like to know if I can use cases when taking input from a csv file:
Instead of generating multiple csv files, I would like to do the following 
In my `tex` file:

```
Input from line 1-10 of file.csv draw plot1.
Input from line 11-20 of file.csv draw plot2.
```

I use the following in my tex file:

```
\addplot[red!30,fill] table[x="Param: length",y="Score", col sep=comma, ignore chars=\%,comment chars={T}] {file.csv};
```

which take as input all lines in the `file.csv`. But would like to add some improvements.

Thank you.

Comment: The second plot should be usable via option `skip first n=10`, but there is no `skip last n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{0:9}` (note that `\coordindex` uses zero-based indexing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1 10
2 11
3 9
4 12
5 10
6 11
7 9
8 10
9 12
10 9
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{0:4}] table {data.dat};
\addplot +[restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{7:9}] table {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried to add the exact line as you but I get an error, should I add `restrict x to domain={\coordindex}{0:4}]` and same for y ?

Comment: @Bionix1441: What error message do you get?

Comment: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/restrict x' and I am goin
g to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: @Bionix1441: The key is called `restrict expr to domain`, not `restrict x`.

Comment: I just tried this and it works, but only if `restrict expr to domain` is the first key in `addplot`'s key list. Hope this might help for someone debugging this later on.

Comment: @Ghostkeeper: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. If I use `\addplot +[black, restrict expr to domain={\coordindex}{0:4}] table {data.dat};`, the code works as expected. Maybe you could open a new question with a minimal example that reproduces the problem?